# python selenium как вытащить ссылку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

есть вот такой элемент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как вытащить ссылку?

браузер: fire fox

Comment: [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: @Jack_oS я взял этот скриншот как пример стало просто интересно как вытащить ссылку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите конкретного объекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем элемент

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/header/div[3]/nav/a[2]/@href")
```

В конце просто добавляем **@href** и он вернет ссылку

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
```